# Download image from ftp with authentication

Tags: ios, swift, http, ftp, swift3

When I try to download image from web site "http://...", this code works good:

```
let link = "http://..."
let url = URL(string: link)
let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
if (data != nil)
{
    imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)!
}
```

How can I download image from "ftp://..." with login and password?